# Describing quantity: "code-length less than # lines" or "less than # lines code-length"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, quantifiers, terminology

Which one is correct?

> code-length less than # lines

Or

> less than # lines code-length

Also, Should I write 'code-length' (with hyphen) or as separate words 'code length'?

Comment: What's the sentence you're trying to use this phrase in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Code-length* is not a familiar hyphenated term. People will understand it, but they will wonder why you said it that way when it is not usual.

It would be more normal to say any of the following, if you're using full sentences:

> The length of code should be less than # lines
>   There should be fewer than # lines of code.

If you're using fragments, such as in a summary list of specifications, I would use something like:

> Fewer than # lines of code
>   Code to comprise fewer than # lines